# How to split aMaharashtra_dPune in two different columns ex state and city in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

I want to split State Maharshtra separate and city Pune separate

```
DECLARE @str varchar(30)
SET @str = 'CMaharashtra_dPune'
SELECT value from STRING_SPLIT((SUBSTRING(@str,2,len(@str))),'_');

I am getting
O/p
Maharashtra
dPune
```

I want it in 1 line

Comment: You want them in rows or columns?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @name varchar(50)
SET @name = 'aMaharashtra_dPune'
select 
    SUBSTRING(@name, 2, CHARINDEX('_', @name) - 2) as state , 
    SUBSTRING(@name, CHARINDEX('_', @name) + 2, LEN(@name)) as city
```

Comment: Is that an answer? Or a clarification of your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can split first then apply the substrings

```
SELECT substring(value, 2, len(value)-1) from 
STRING_SPLIT('CMaharashtra_dPune','_');
```

Output:

```
Maharashtra
Pune
```

Comment: I wanted in one line

Comment: I did ask that in comment to clarify but you didn't reply :P